# Box viewer.js API scroll within div

Tags: box-view-api, crocodoc

I’m implementing the Box view within a div, not an iframe, and the functions which use scrolling are not working. Is this because Box view expects the window or the iframe to scroll and not on a div? The scroll events such as scrollstart, scrolled and anything else with scrolling doesn’t seem to fire.  The Zoom events seem to be working fine and I have used the same format for them as for the scroll events.

I know it would help to show code but I’m hoping someone knows the answer off the top of their head.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some code would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The primary mistake I was making was to try to copy the generated code in the examples where one uses an iframe as the container. I was copying a bunch of classes from there on to the div container I was using to put the viewer into. When I removed all the classes except "viewer" it worked. As for the iframe, the viewer.js inserts multiple iframes into the container. There isn't a way without iframes. However, the issues I had when I was using an iframe as the starting container (interacting with other plugins) went away when I used the div.viewer. Also, it seems that the viewer.js doesn't have the controls that come with the box one using an iframe as the primary container and so far I'm having success with separate divs like so:

```
<div class="viewer"></div>
<div class="viewer-error">...</div>
<div class="controls-container">...</div>
```